# how to create dynamic table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dynamic pivoted query which generates a result set and I want to insert that data into a table. But the problem is columns are dropped or generated by the time. So by the time I cannot predict columns. That is why I created a dynamic pivoted dataset. So how to insert that data set into table?

One solution is to drop and recreate the table every time but I don't know how to do it. I tried `CTE`, `TEM`P table but `EXEC` support only select, insert, update, delete statement:

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sqlquery NVARCHAR(MAX), @orderby Nvarchar(MAX),@value Nvarchar(max);
SET @columns = N'';
SET @value=N'0'
SELECT @columns += N', ' + QUOTENAME([Note_Type])
FROM 
(
    SELECT  distinct 
        No_T
    FROM [DS_DM].[dbo].[DAILY_TABLE]
    where No_T not in (570,80,150,590,80,99)
)as A order by No_T

SET @sqlquery = N'
Select 
K._Number
,D.C_Number
,' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
from 
(
    select 
        _Number
        ,' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
    from 
    (
        select distinct  
            right(REPLICATE('+@value+',11) +_Number,11) as [_Number]
            ,No_t
            ,No_T_Des
      FROM [DS_DM].[dbo].[DAILY_TABLE]
      where No_T not in (570,80,150,590,80,99) 
    )AS J
    pivot
    (
    count(No_T_Des) FOR [No_t] IN ('
      + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
      + ') 
    )P 
)K
left join 
[DS_DM].[dbo].[D_TABLE] D on k._Number = D._Number
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlquery
```

Comment: Would SELECT INTO be an option ? [SELECT INTO] (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp)

Comment: i alredy tried select into as well but it didnt work because what if next time my query ran and column defination is change it will insert value into diffrent columns

Comment: The problem is i can not predict table defination.

Comment: Ah Yes. Ok, Any reason why you can't have a fixed table name, and just drop and recreate the table each time you run the query ?

Comment: So, run this before building your dynamic SQL. `IF OBJECT_ID (N'TEMP_TABLE', N'U') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
 DROP TABLE TEMP_TABLE
END` Then do a SELECT INTO TEMP_TABLE which will recreate it for you.

Comment: and how am i going to create this table based on result set ???

Comment: See modified code in answer. The first part will delete it if it exists. Your main query will then recreate the table. As you have a pre-defined table name. You can then query this table afterwards.

Comment: What's the purpose of this table you want to create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answers to my questions.

there are 2 fileds which remais static every time. so I've created ETL that drop that table and recreate every single day with those two fileds. and rest of the 66 columns which are dynamic (drops or newly created) every day. so i've made a cursor for that which loop through all of that categories and altering that table that've created and added that code to ETL

So bassically Every single day that ETL Runs  Drop the existing table, Create new table with the 2 static filds and altering same table using cursor with the dynamic filds.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code to reflect my proposed solution.

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'NEW_TABLE', N'U') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
DROP TABLE NEW_TABLE 
END 


DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sqlquery NVARCHAR(MAX), @orderby Nvarchar(MAX),@value Nvarchar(max);
SET @columns = N'';
SET @value=N'0'
SELECT @columns += N', ' + QUOTENAME([Note_Type])
FROM 
(
    SELECT  distinct 
        No_T
    FROM [DS_DM].[dbo].[DAILY_TABLE]
    where No_T not in (570,80,150,590,80,99)
)as A order by No_T

SET @sqlquery = N'
Select 
K._Number
,D.C_Number
,' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '

INTO NEW_TABLE 
from 
(
    select 
        _Number
        ,' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
    from 
    (
        select distinct  
            right(REPLICATE('+@value+',11) +_Number,11) as [_Number]
            ,No_t
            ,No_T_Des
      FROM [DS_DM].[dbo].[DAILY_TABLE]
      where No_T not in (570,80,150,590,80,99) 
    )AS J
    pivot
    (
    count(No_T_Des) FOR [No_t] IN ('
      + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
      + ') 
    )P 
)K
left join 
[DS_DM].[dbo].[D_TABLE] D on k._Number = D._Number
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlquery
```